# My wife ticked 'No' to a question 'Have you been known by any other name', would it hinder my approval eventhough she has been approved

Tags: visa-refusals

My wife has filled and submitted her form for student UK visa, she filled me in has dependant (partner details), but she filled her family name as her surname and ticked 'No' to the question 'Have you been known by any other name'.

We got married a few months before she filled her form and hasn't used my surname in any documentation or ID-card.

She has submitted the form and has been approved for visa, but I'm about to fill my form and I'm worried if her answer to that question might affect my application.

Comment: It would appear she has indeed not used any other name. When you fill in your form, what name will you put for your wife?

Comment: If you and your wife were Spanish, it would be unusual if she had used another name.  If you and your wife were Japanese, it would be unusual if she had not used another name.  UK Visa staff do not make general assumptions about this, which is why they ask the question; they want to see whether they have information related to any name that has been used for this individual.  Just tell the truth and make sure that her name on her passport and on her application and her name on your application are the same so they can be matched.

Answer (score 12):

If all of her documentation uses her maiden (pre-marriage) name then I believe that this is the correct answer.  You should answer truthfully but, from what you say, she has.  If you are also truthful then I cannot see how this would prejudice your application.  Of course, if you need to prove that you are married then your names will not help and you would need your marriage certificate but I expect that you would anyway.

The tradition here in the UK is that a woman takes her husband's name on marriage but it is increasingly common for women to not do so.  I don't have any statistics but in the sample of my family (me, one brother, and two sisters), I am the only one who shares a surname with their spouse.  Many of my married, female friends and colleagues do not use their husbands' names.  It is also becoming common to use a hyphenated name and sometimes the man does as well.  I don't expect that anyone (outside of remote areas) would be surprised by a married couple who did not share a name.  Someone working with visa applications must be very much used to this.  The only rule today on what name to expect someone's wife to use is to not expect anything.

Suppose Alice Smith marries Bill Jones.  Traditionally, she would change her name to Alice Jones.  However, today, she might remain as Alice Smith or change to Alice Smith Jones, Alice Smith-Jones, Alice Jones-Smith, or maybe something else.  The man might change as well e.g. Bill Jones-Smith.

And this just covers straight marriages.  Of course, there is no long standing tradition for other cases so each couple makes their own decision.

Answer (score 2):

In some (many?) countries it is usual for married women not to change their name into that of the husband.
It is not common but certainly not unheard of in the UK, so I doubt the visa officials will worry, as long as both of you mention the other, and by the same name.
That is the names she mentioned on her forms, not both on your family name.

Comment: It's not traditional here and probably not typical either but far from rare.  My wife took my name.  One sister married more than  40 years ago but did not take her husband's name.   My other sister took her husband's name on her first marriage (over 50 years ago) but not her second husband's name after remarriage a few years later.  So, rather oddly, she still is using her first husband's name.  I know lots of other married women who have not taken their husband's names.  In the latest family marriage, my niece did not take her husband's name.

Comment: @badjohn your Other Sister realised what a faff it is changing your name everywhere, and didn't want to go through it all again even though it means carrying an "outdated" surname.    That shows what a lot of work it can be.

Comment: @Criggie She had her reasons beyond just laziness.